# Access variable in child component that is defined in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access someVariable, defined in Parent function, in Child function.

```
import React from "react";

export default function Parent(props) {
    // Variable is definded
    const someVariable = false;

    return <div className="parentClass">{props.children}</div>;
}

Parent.Child = function(props) {
    // Want to access someVariable defined in parent function
    return someVariable && <div className="childClass">Should render if someVariable is true</div>;
}

// Use like this later
<Parent>
    // This will be rendered only if someVariable is true
    <Parent.Child />
</Parent>
```

Comment: pass it as a property to child component from parent?

Comment: Pass it as a `prop` to the children?

Comment: you can pass that variable as a prop to the child component.

Comment: If this is exactly the scenario as in your code in this post, you just need to use that variable in parent like `<div className="someClass">{someVariable  && props.children}</div>`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your variable in the parent component as a prop to the child component:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

    return (
       <View><Text>{props.someVariable}</Text></View>
    )
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
   const someVariable = false;

   return (
      <ChildComponent someVariable={someVariable} />
   )
}
```